# How to add vertical space after gather

Tags: spacing, equations

I want some vertical space after the equation but \[1em] and \vspace{1em} do not work properly. It adds always the same amount of space, even if I write 70em or other units.

For example

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,float}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}

\begin{document}
Il momento flettente anche in questo caso è pari a\vspace{.5em}
\begin{gather*}
    M_x=F(L-z)\\
    M_{x_{max}}=FL\\[.5em]
\end{gather*}
Lo sforzo normale all'incastro è quindi pari
\end{document}
```

gives me this result:

[image]

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx. Could you add a compilable example (`\documentclass` etc.), please?

Comment: Did you try `\vskip k em`?

Comment: I just added the compilable example, thank you.
I tried \vskip and it let me at least control the vertical space. The strange thing is that extra vertical space is added, so to get the desired positioning I have to use \vskip -2em. After equation usually  I just use \vspace{.5em}, but in align and gather I always get this problem

Comment: So the question is: I set the display skips to zero; how do I add back the space I removed? There is no point in setting those values to zero. It's wrong to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the last `\\​` inside the `gather*` environment, but you should probably also remove the other manually set vertical space as well. You will then get:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,float}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}

\begin{document}
Il momento flettente anche in questo caso è pari a
\begin{gather*}
    M_x=F(L-z) \\
    M_{x_{max}}=FL
\end{gather*}

Lo sforzo normale all'incastro è quindi pari
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You can use the macros `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` which you initially set to 0pt to change the spacing locally (since this is their job anyway):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,float}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}

\begin{document}

Qualche altro testo che ha solo una funzione esemplare
\begin{gather*}
    M_x=F(L-z) \\
    M_{x_{max}}=FL
\end{gather*}

Ancora più altro testo che non ha una vera funzione

\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{1cm}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{1cm}
Il momento flettente anche in questo caso è pari a 
\begin{gather*}
    M_x=F(L-z) \\
    M_{x_{max}}=FL
\end{gather*}

Lo sforzo normale all'incastro è quindi pari
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want to choose by myself the vertical space before and after the equation, your solution does not give me this possibility.

Comment: But this is exactly, what `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` are meant for. Just set the values to, say, 1cm before you typeset the next `gather*` environment.